# what is used for the directory in a rdiff backup command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command, backup, rdiff-backup

I need to delete backups to open space on my server.  Though I don't know what the directory I should specify is in the command to delete them `rdiff-backup --remove-older-than 20B host.net::/remote-dir`.  So far my directory looks like this on the backup server.

```
\home\admin\server1\
```

Then I have a folder inside that called `rdiff-backup-data`.  This is in addition to other folders, but is this the one I should direct the command to?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [rdiff-backup man page](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup.1.html), you use the **destination directory** along with the `--remove-older-than` option. The destination directory is the one that *contains* the `rdiff-backup-data` directory.

Besides the directory issue, you also have an incorrect *time spec* for the `--remove-older-than` option. Quoting the documentation,

```
          time_spec can be either an absolute time, like "2002-01-04",  or
          a  time  interval.   The time interval is an integer followed by
          the character s, m, h, D, W, M, or Y, indicating  seconds,  min-
          utes,  hours,  days,  weeks, months, or years respectively, or a
          number of these concatenated.  For example, 32m  means  32  min-
          utes,  and 3W2D10h7s means 3 weeks, 2 days, 10 hours, and 7 sec-
          onds.  In this context, a month means 30 days,  a  year  is  365
          days, and a day is always 86400 seconds.
```

If you are just running this once, you'll probably be removing multiple increments, in which case you'll also need the `--force` option.